# regex/wildcard in scp

Tags: shell, unix, file-transfer, scp

Is it possible to use a wildcard in scp

I am trying to achieve:

```
loop
{
   substitue_host (scp path/file.jar user@host:path1/foo*/path2/jar/)
}
```

I keep on getting "scp: ambiguous target"

Actually I am calling an api with source and dest that uses scp underneath and loops over diff hosts to put files

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

In general, yes, it is certainly possible to use a wildcard in scp.

But, in your scp command, the second argument is the target, the first argument is the source.  You certainly cannot copy a source into multiple targets.

If you were trying to copy multiple jars, for example, then the following would certainly work:

```
scp path/*.jar user@host:path2/jar/
```

"ambigious target" in this case is specifically complaining that the wildcard you're using results in multiple possible target directories on the @host system.

---  EDIT:

If you want to copy to multiple directories on a remote system and have to determine them dynamically, a script like the following should work:

```
 dir_list=$(ssh user@host ls -d '/path1/foo*/path2/jar/')

 for dir in $dir_list; do
     scp path/file.jar user@host:$dir
 done
```

The `dir_list` variable will hold the results of the execution of the `ls` on the remote system.  The `-d` is so that you get the directory names, not their contents.  The single quotes are to ensure that wildcard expansion waits to execute on the remote system, not on the local system.

And then you'll loop through each dir to do the remote copy into that directory.

(All this is ksh syntax, btw.)

Comment: thnx. I wonder why copying a source to multiple targets not possible [not implemented] . It is certainly someone might want to do ?

I will wait for few more answers else accept this one. My problem is still unsolved but I guess my question is answered :)

Comment: In `cp` and all it's derivatives, it would be ambiguous to allow multiple targets -- if there were three files in a `cp` command, does that means 2 sources or 1 target, or 1 source and 2 targets?  If you want to copy to multiple targets, loop it and feed the targets in one-by-one.

Comment: I see the ambiguity .. and seems like by design it was decided to allow multiple source and single target [however there could have been a flag to specify the options or may be a diff delimenter than space could be used between list of sources and targets] ... What I was trying to do using wildcard (*) was essentially looping across all the targets that would match :) .. since I dont know exact targets but a pattern .. probably there is some utility that allows that ..

Comment: See my final edit above.  This should get you most of the way to what I think you're trying to do.